# How to javafx Translate Transition Repeat

Tags: java, javafx

Here is a picture of what I want to do:

[image: img]

After the first move, I want to give the second move.

Path Transition allows movement, but I want to make it move at a right angle.

Is there a way to do two moves with translation?

```
package application;

import javafx.animation.TranslateTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;


public class Main extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,350,350);
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 40, 40);
        Rectangle point = new Rectangle(0, 0, 10, 10);
        Rectangle point2 = new Rectangle(300, 0, 10, 10);
        Rectangle point3 = new Rectangle(300, 300, 10, 10);
        root.getChildren().addAll(rect, point, point2, point3);
        
        TranslateTransition tt = new TranslateTransition(new Duration(1000), rect);
        tt.setFromX(0);
        tt.setFromY(0);
        
        tt.setToX(300);
        tt.setToY(0);
        tt.play();          
        
        TranslateTransition tt2 = new TranslateTransition(new Duration(1000), rect);
        tt2.setFromY(0);
        tt2.setToY(300);
        tt2.play();
        
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

Comment: You can use a `SequentialTransition` to make animations play one after the other. Though you could instead use a single `PathTransition` with an appropriate `Path` to achieve the same animation in this case.

Comment: Thank you. I solved it thanks to you. It's the best.

Comment: you might consider to answer and accept your own question (with the code the solves it) to make it helpful for future readers :)

Comment: Please do put the working code as an answer - so others can benefit!